# Creating subfolders in a bucket dynamilcally on Amazon s3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

Is it possible to create subfolder dynamically in a bucket? I am following this [a link](http://www.cheynewallace.com/uploading-to-s3-with-angularjs/)link to upload image on S3, so I need to create a folder dynamicaly on s3 and then upload image there. If possible how can this be done.

Also, could you please suggest me the best way to store your bucket credentials in an angularjs application. Currently I am simply, fetching it from js file.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a *very serious flaw* in the notion of a "public IAM user" as discussed in the blog post you cited.  Even if the user in question is heavily restricted, this is still arguably a violation of the [AWS terms of service](http://aws.amazon.com/agreement) and a very foolhardy practice.  You simply can't allow the browser access to your credentials for any reason.  Your approach needs to be entirely different, not "fetching" your credentials at all.

Comment: Additionally, questions posted to SO should be limited to one question or problem.  You have asked two very different questions, and the more serious one isn't even mentioned in the title of the post.

Comment: Yes I dont want to fetch the credentials the way it is done here. I am searching for a safe way to fetch the credentials and then upload the images. No luck till now..

Comment: yep you are correct, actually I mixed two issues here.

Comment: Could you please suggest me some good way to how can I fetch the credentials then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS S3 doesn't have real directory concept. It only has bucket and objects.

You only need to upload your image into a bucket. The image file name could contain `/`.

Comment: Could you please suggest me the best way to store bucket credentials in an angularjs application. Currently I am simply, fetching it from js file.

Comment: What do you mean by fetching from js? Never put the credential (access key and secret key) inside js. Use AWS Cognito or Web Identity Federation instead. Read more in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html.

Comment: I am just fetching these credentials locally, I dont want this so I wanted some solution..